# Re-opening questions that have been closed for perhaps the wrong reason

Tags: support, voting-to-close, voting-to-reopen

There's a vote to re-open this question: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/12608/is-there-a-book-on-commons-available that's popped up in the review queue, and I was wondering how to handle it.

The question was closed as an exact duplicate of https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/10023/is-there-any-good-site-to-learn-drupal-7, which it doesn't appear to be, so I think the close reason is probably incorrect.

However it's a request for a book recommendation which would ideally be closed as not constructive.

What's the best thing to do in this situation? Vote to re-open the question so it can then be closed again with a more appropriate reason, or vote to keep it closed with the current reason? Or none of the above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you vote to re-open the question, it means you think the question has been wrongly closed, and it should stay open.

You should not vote to re-open a question just to change the closing reason. Once the question is closed (and it should stay closed), the closing reason doesn't have any relevance.
It is true that it could be confusing for who tries to understand which questions to ask, but who is confused about the allowed questions can ask on this very site, to know better.

Use the "Leave Closed" button, for such cases.